# Python OLS with categorical label

Tags: statsmodels, categorical-data

I have a dataset where I am trying to predict the type of car based off of a number of features. I would like to an OLS regression to see

```
import statsmodels.api as sm

X  = features 
# where 0 = sedan, 1 = minivan , etc 
y = [0,0,1,0,2,....]

X2 = sm.add_constant(np.array(X))
est = sm.OLS(np.array(y), X2)
est2 = est.fit()
```

^ I don't feel like doing this is correct because I am not specifying that it is categorical, I feel like the functional form should change. Was wondering if anyone had any insight on this.

Comment: If the dependent variable is categorical, then the appropriate model is a version of Multinomial Logit, which is the extension of Logit to the case when we have more than two levels or choices in the categorical response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Ordinary least squares** regression assumes a  *numerical* dependent variable, you cannot use it to predict categorical outcomes.

To predict *categorical* outcomes with a regression model, you want to use **multinomial logistic regression**, for example using [sklearn](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.html).